# Error when importing Firebase Crashlytics library

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics

I try to migrate my Android application from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics. I follow the documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android&authuser=0#add-crashlytics and when I add the library into my project, i have an error with okhttp3 when i launch my app :

```
    2020-07-08 12:17:05.393 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: AbstractApplication.uncaughtException: No virtual method callTimeout(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder; in class Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder' appears in /data/app/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev-2/base.apk:classes10.dex)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.394 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< START class fr.lundimatin.commons.AbstractApplication.uncaughtException>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2020-07-08 12:17:05.394 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.<clinit>(HttpRequest.java:46)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.394 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequestFactory.buildHttpRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:43)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.394 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.AbstractSpiCall.getHttpRequest(AbstractSpiCall.java:113)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.394 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:80)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.394 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.395 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.395 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.395 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.395 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.395 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:60)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.395 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.395 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
2020-07-08 12:17:05.395 4868-4923/fr.lundimatin.rovercash.gemma.dev E/LM_LOG_GENERAL: <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< END class fr.lundimatin.commons.AbstractApplication.uncaughtException>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Into my build.gradle i have :

```
api "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.0"
api "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.7.0"

api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.0'
```

Comment: try changing okhttp version to     ```api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'```

Comment: Can you follow these steps to upgrade to new Firebase crashlytics SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?authuser=0&platform=ios

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tired to upgrade the ksoap2 version to 3.6.4, it worked for me

ksoap2 repositories jar:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/

There are similar problems here.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1741

Comment: The link just indicates where the repository is. The essential part of the answer is that the version is wrong.